# Decorator to mark a method to be executed no more than once even if called several times

Tags: python, class, methods, decorator

I will go straight to the example:

```
class Foo:
  @execonce
  def initialize(self):
    print 'Called'

>>> f1 = Foo()
>>> f1.initialize()
Called
>>> f1.initialize()
>>> f2 = Foo()
>>> f2.initialize()
Called
>>> f2.initialize()
>>>
```

I tried to define `execonce` but could not write one that works with methods.

PS: I cannot define the code in `__init__` for `initialize` has to be called *sometime after* the object is initialized. cf - [cmdln issue 13](http://code.google.com/p/cmdln/issues/detail?id=13&can=1)

Comment: Lateral comment: I suggest you not to ignore the second call. Instead, you should raise an exception. If a caller is initializing twice, something wrong is happening, and you should report it rather than silently ignore it. Of course, I don't know your specific problem.

Comment: Stefano, I agree .. this feels odd to me too. Basically, the test cases call these subcommand methods (eg: 'svn commit') like this: `command.do_commit` and `command.do_update` sequentially. And each of these subcommands have to call the `initialize` method (see cmdln issue 13). I don't want to raise exceptions .. as why would the caller (a test case) need to be aware of such an internal detail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import functools

def execonce(f):

    @functools.wraps(f)
    def donothing(*a, **k):
        pass

    @functools.wraps(f)
    def doit(self, *a, **k):
        try:
            return f(self, *a, **k)
        finally:
            setattr(self, f.__name__, donothing)

    return doit
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: donothing() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)`

Comment: Ok, by removing the `self` argument from the `donothing` method .. I was able to make this work.

Comment: I would recommend adding functools.wraps decorator to doit and donothing. This way documentation and other properties of the function will be the same.

Comment: @srid, oops, edited to remove the self. @Manuel, yes, let me edit to do that too...

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
class Foo:
  def __init__(self):
    self.initialize_called = False
  def initialize(self):
    if self.initalize_called:
        return
    self.initialize_called = True
    print 'Called'
```

This is straightforward and easy to read. There is another instance variable and some code required in the `__init__` function, but it would satisfy your requirements.

Comment: I would like to avoid doing this for every class in my code .. and prefer a decorator or something for the benefit of the DRY principle.

Answer (score 0):

try something similar to this

```
def foo():
     try:
             foo.called
     except:
             print "called"
             foo.called = True
```

methods and functions are objects. you can add methods and attributes on them. This can be useful for your case. If you want a decorator, just have the decorator allocate the method but first, check the flag. If the flag is found, a null method is returned and consequently executed.

Comment: This may not work as the method (on which the decorator is called) is not yet bounded to an object .. and `initialize` is to be called once *for each object* .. not all objects.